# How to properly pip3 install network to use LoRa

Tags: raspberry-pi3, micropython, lora

I can't seem to find someone explaining what I have to do exactly in order to be able to make my code compile the very first line `from network import LoRa`.

I browsed through this network.py and it doesn't even mention LoRa (nor lora actually), I watched the micro python doc without any success.

I read somewhere I need to install `upip` but I'm not so sure what I'm doing wrong, noone seem to have trouble with the imports.

My Raspberry 3 successfully detect my PyCom device in USB.

Comment: Are you looking at this [code](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/devices/lopy/usage/index.html)? Because that is specifc to the node in micropython

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the device first through the USB serial port.

The module comes with its own Python interpreter / REPL which is running on the embedded MCU.

I suggest you look at https://docs.pycom.io/gettingstarted/ and also post on https://forum.pycom.io if you have more detailed questions.